# method plugin doesn't work within Function Constructor

Tags: javascript, json, function, iframe, constructor

What I'm trying to achieve in JavaScript is to make a method of the plugin I'm working with (called "Plugin") flexible. The plugin runs in an iFrame and has cross-domain trust settings applied. I want to use variables to build the method parameter rather than hard code it.

The **hardcoded version** is shown below and I've double checked this works. I've used it in functions and in a Function constructor. Both work.

```
    window.Plugin.Session.Tags({ 
    TagName: 'SomeTagName',
    TagValueTagging: 'sometagvalue; secondtagvalue',
    TagValueTaggingReset: '*'
    }).Update();
```

My objective is to replace the 'sometagvalue' with a variable, so I can set the tag dynamically. The help says the parameter is a constant JSON string. 
I've tried the following things:

1. build the **parameter as string**. **Result:** Though myText holds the exact same string as in the hardcoded version, the method is not executed.

```
    var myTag = '\\'DEELNEMER ; name\\' ';
    var myText = "{TagName : 'Workflow'," +
    " TagValueTagging : " + myTag  +
    ", TagValueTaggingReset : '*'}";
    alert("myText = " + myText);
    x = window.Plugin.Session.Tags(myText);
    x.Update();
```

2) using new **Function constructor**. I created a variable with the session object and inserted that as parameter. In order to proof myself that I working with the right object, I've put it's LID in an alert as well outside as inside the constructor. **Result:** the Session.LID was the same inside and outside the constructor, but tagging did not happen.

```
    var myFunction = "alert(\"in constructor Session.LID = \" + prmSession.LID); window.addTag = 
    prmSession.Tags({TagName : \'Workflow\', TagValueTagging : \'DEELNEMER\' , TagValueTaggingReset : 
    \'*\'}); window.addTag.Update();" 
    var addTagFunction = new Function("prmSession", myFunction)
    var prmSession = window.Plugin.Session;
    alert("in main function Session.LID = " + prmSession.LID);
    addTagFunction(prmSession);
```

3) using **JSON stringify**. Again **Result:** Tag was not set, in neither variant..

```
    var myTag = 'DEELNEMER ; name ';
    var obj = new Object();
    obj.TagName = "Workflow";
    obj.TagValueTagging = myTag;
    obj.TagValueTaggingReset = "*";<br/>
    var myJSON= JSON.stringify(obj);
    Plugin.Session.Tags(myJSON).Update();<br/>
    /*variant 2*/<br/>
    var myObjParsed = JSON.parse(myJSON);
    Plugin.Session.Tags(myObjParsed).Update();
```

I would be very greatful for a tip how to solve this issue.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Plugin appears to translate the javascript into backend data queries during the compilation of the solution.
The use of parameters is therefore not possible.